# IPtables blocking SSH only if using conntrack

Tags: centos, iptables, conntrack

### Error

As you can see, the only difference between the working and the not working configuration is `-m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED`. If I use `-m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED` it does not work either... But Why?!

After few tests, I have noticed that every rules using `conntrack` does not work...
Can you explain me why is SSH blocked by `iptables` only when I use `conntrack`?

Thanks :-)

### Working configuration

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_IP="X.X.X.X"

iptables -F
iptables -X

# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow previous connections
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming ssh only
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${SERVER_IP} --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${SERVER_IP} --dport 22 -j LOG --log-prefix "[ACCEPT INPUT][SSH] "


# make sure nothing comes or goes out of this box
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "[DROP INPUT][DEFAULT] "
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

### Not working configuration

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVER_IP="X.X.X.X"

iptables -F
iptables -X

# Setting default filter policy
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP

# Allow previous connections
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

# Allow unlimited traffic on loopback
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

# Allow incoming ssh only
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${SERVER_IP} --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d ${SERVER_IP} --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j LOG --log-prefix "[ACCEPT INPUT][SSH] "


# make sure nothing comes or goes out of this box
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix "[DROP INPUT][DEFAULT] "
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

[EDIT]

### How am I sure that conntrack is involved?

Because in the log file I can see something like this :

`[DROP][INPUT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:...:00 SRC=X.X.X.X DST=X.X.X.X LEN=67 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=41 ID=39550 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51093 DPT=22 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP`

`[DROP][INPUT]` is the last rule in my iptables configuration file.

Comment: And how do you recognize that the rules with -m conntrack do not work? Because you do not see log entry? Your rules are built in a way that you WILL NOT reach logging entries which follow -j ACCEPT rules (as it terminates processing).

Comment: That's right, this is an error.
But I recognize that the rules with -m conntrack do not work because logs are only `[DROP][INPUT]`, so this is my default rule.

Comment: Does the DST=X.X.X.X from log file match with your ${SERVER_IP}?

Comment: The log entry you posted doesn't correspond to any of the iptables rules you posted. What is the real log entry and real iptables rules?

Comment: @Tomek : yes DST=<My Server IP>

Comment: @MichaelHampton : From `/var/log/messages`

`Dec 15 15:21:58 loki kernel: Dec 15 17:38:54 loki kernel: [DROP INPUT][DEFAULT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:[...]:00 SRC=X.X.X.X DST=<My Server IP> LEN=67 TOS=0x08 PREC=0x20 TTL=41 ID=39550 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51093 DPT=22 WINDOW=229 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP`

Comment: OK, then please post the corresponding iptables rules?

Comment: You where right, I have done some test after my post and I does not past the corresponding log file.

Comment: @Tomek There are other ways to test you know. Have a set with and without. You don't need logging for everything. Anyway I've been noticing the same problem and I do log. There is something odd going on. More frustrating is this has only started on a new install - it was working fine before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This time I know how to make it work, without knowing why this is not working.
Restarting `iptables` service make my script working: `systemctl restart iptables`.

Before working on this simple script, I was trying to implement another one, much more longer. It apply new rules in other CHAINS like PREROUTING and other customs.
This script must have forced `iptables` to stop working with `cstate` or `conntrack`, maybe by filling a table to it maximum?

Answer (score 0):

*Thank you all for your answers!
I finally figured it out, when I have removed `firewalld` in favor of `iptables` it seems that I have remove also some dependencies.
After removing and then installing again iptables my configuration became fonctionnal.*

[EDIT]
Actualy this is still not working :-(

In logs I noticed that "SYN" and "ACK SYN" paquets are dropped by `iptables`:

```
Dec 17 08:03:38 loki kernel: [DROP][INPUT][DEFAULT] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:...:00 SRC=myIP DST=serverIP LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=12527 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51942 DPT=22 WINDOW=64240 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Dec 17 08:03:38 loki kernel: [DROP][OUTPUT][DEFAULT] IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=serverIP DST=myIP LEN=52 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=22 DPT=51942 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 ACK SYN URGP=0
Dec 17 08:03:38 loki kernel: [INPUT][DROP][NOT SYN] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:...:00 SRC=myIP DST=serverIP LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=12528 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51942 DPT=22 WINDOW=256 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Dec 17 08:03:38 loki kernel: [ACCEPT][INPUT][SSH] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=0c:c4:...:00 SRC=myIP DST=serverIP LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=120 ID=12528 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=51942 DPT=22 WINDOW=256 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Dec 17 08:03:38 loki sshd[5074]: Connection from myIP port 51942 on serverIP port 22
Dec 17 08:03:39 loki sshd[5074]: Accepted password for myUSER from myIP port 51942 ssh2
Dec 17 08:03:39 loki systemd-logind: New session 307 of user myUSER.
Dec 17 08:03:39 loki systemd: Started Session 307 of user myUSER.
```

As you will see in my rules, I did not drop paquets for real for my tests, to keep connected to my server.
Here the script used:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    #
    # =========
    # Reset ALL
    # =========
    #
    iptables="iptables"
    ip6tables="ip6tables"

    # HARD RESET
    $iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
    $iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
    $iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
    $iptables -F
    $iptables -X
    # $iptables -t nat -F
    # $iptables -t mangle -F


    ## Drop broadcast (without log)
    $iptables -A INPUT -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP
    $iptables -A FORWARD -m pkttype --pkt-type broadcast -j DROP
    $iptables -A INPUT -d 255.255.255.255 -j DROP
    $iptables -A FORWARD -d 255.255.255.255 -j DROP

    # Keep connections opened
    # DO NOT USE RELATED? https://gist.github.com/azlux/6a70bd38bb7c525ab26efe7e3a7ea8ac
    $iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    $iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

    #
    # ===============
    # Allow localhost
    # ===============
    #
    $iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
    $iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT

    #
    # ====
    # IPv6
    # ====
    #
    $ip6tables -P INPUT DROP
    $ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT
    $ip6tables -P FORWARD DROP

    #
    # ===========
    # Allow ports
    # ===========
    #

    ## NEW NOT SYNC
    $iptables -A INPUT -p tcp ! --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j LOG --log-prefix "[INPUT][DROP][NOT SYN] "

    ## DNS (no logs)
    $iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp -s 0/0 --dport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    $iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT


    ## SSH
    $iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j LOG --log-prefix "[ACCEPT][INPUT][SSH] "
    $iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    $iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

    #
    # =================
    # Logs DROP paquets
    # =================
    #
    $iptables -A INPUT -j LOG --log-prefix="[DROP][INPUT][DEFAULT] "
    $iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG --log-prefix="[DROP][FORWARD][DEFAULT] "
    $iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG --log-prefix="[DROP][OUTPUT][DEFAULT] "

    exit 0
```

Comment: I still suspect that `conntrack` or `ctstate` is involved. Is there some prerequisites or something to check?

Comment: I recently have encountered this problem. It happened after a server upgrade which required a reinstall. I used my long working iptables scripts and then I've had firewall problems. I have noticed it's the `conntrack ctstate` that is causing a problem. It's bizarre. I should be able to check for state NEW and that there's a SYN flag. Even having just ctstate NEW without the SYN it fails. Add a rule that doesn't check state and it's fine! It makes no sense at all. I even tested my RAM I was so at odds. I asked a long time friend who I thought might have an answer and he doesn't either!

Comment: And given that it worked before I don't think there is a prerequisite here unless there was some change made that I'm unaware of. I don't know why that would only show itself on a new install though. I was considering nftables but it's at the point I just want the thing to work and CentOS 7 doesn't have the translation tool (though I have access to it I don't know if there are any compatibility issues from Fedora to CentOS 7).